# How many $10$ letter anagrams of KOLMOGOROV don't contain the subword GROOV?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $10$ letter anagrams of KOLMOGOROV don't contain the subword GROOV?

Not sure how to do this one. Obviously there are $\frac{10!}{4!}$ anagrams of KOLMOGOROV but I'm not sure how to account for the overcounting.

Comment: There are six places GROOV can start.  For each such place count the combinations of the other five letters, which should be $5!/2!$. So subtract $6\cdot 5!/2!$.

Comment: Thank you I understand now. You are a genius.

Comment: Hah I wish I was a genius.  But thank you :-)

Comment: I'll go ahead and post that an an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are six places GROOV can start. For each such place count the combinations of the other five letters, which should be $5!/2!$, since those five letters are distinct except for two O's.  So $10!/4!$ overcounts by $6\cdot5!/2!$. So the final answer is $10!/4! - 6⋅5!/2!$.

Comment: Thank. I just read your bio. Very interesting stuff.

Comment: @Will Thanks bro, you brought a smile to my day :-)